# Join head to body while keeping textures and UV's

Tags: uv, objects, texture-painting

I managed to join a head made with FaceBuilder to a Human Generator body in Blender 3.0.
But now I have to match the textures as well. As it can be viewed in the image, there is also a gap in the textures. Can anyone recommend a tutorial or a workflow to be able to make this into a unified texture that I could then texture paint etc? The end purpose is to be able to pose/animate the character (face expression as well), but not for games. It will stay in Blender. Right now the two UV's seem to be overlapped and each affecting a different image texture. Is there a way to put them all together without modifying the original UV's and textures, just join them so I can smoothly work on a single object?
[image: screenshot]

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tmAW6jTFxaUVs72UOnfuHMBzE8Qad7Bz/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There are too many details and gotchas for answering this question in the general sense.  Could you provide a link to your file so we could answer it for your specific case?

Comment: I'm trying for hours to upload the file to blend-exchange. It has 196 Mb and it keeps getting stuck at some point. Do you know a better solution to share the blend file here?

Comment: Simplify the file-- we need the head mesh and the body mesh, materials, but no images.  And enable compression in the sidebar for the save dialog.

Comment: Shared it on Google drive, seemed the better solution for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your materials are complicated.  You have multiple textures for each material-- you can't make a single image for everything, because there's more than four channels of info there.  This isn't trivial.  I'll explain what I can.

In general, it's fine that your UVs overlap.  They reference different images, so they can overlap.  But to make images that represent everything, we need a new UV map.  So on properties/object data/UV, we'll hit the plus button to create one.  Then, editing that map, in the UV editor, we'll do a "pack all" operation to eliminate overlap:

[image]

Now, like I said, there are multiple channels of information here.  We can't just make one image to capture the entire material; we need multiple images.  But the general process here is to bake those elements to new images.

For each material, we need an actively selected image texture node, with a new image-- the same image for every material:

[image]

Once we have made that for one material, we can copy and paste it into other materials.  Every material needs this node.  It shouldn't be plugged into anything, and nothing needs to be plugged into it.

After that, take a look at properties/render/bake.  Set your bake type to "Diffuse", then uncheck Direct and Indirect, leaving only Color checked.  (Direct and Indirect refer to lighting.  Color will bake the base diffuse color from our materials.  If we enabled Direct and/or Indirect, this color would be multiplied with how much light our surfaces were receiving.)

Then, hit bake, and go to sleep.  When you wake, you'll find your new diffuse color image, on your new UV map:

[image]

First thing to do is to save the image.  The instant Blender decides it needs a little bit of RAM, it'll forget the image.  So save early.

Next step is to plug that in to your materials.  We could figure out every place, on each of your materials, that should be using a diffuse color input, and replace it with this new image, referenced by your new UV map, like this, for your head material:

[image]

But knowing where you should put your diffuse on each of your materials requires understanding all of your materials-- something that I'm not willing to do, and something that requires a good understanding of materials to begin with, one which you may not have.

Another thing we can do is just make a new material and assign everything to it:

[image]

Doing this, we lose all of the details of your existing materials, but we retain the diffuse color, which is the most important bit.  We have a diffuse texture for the whole model, and we can texture paint on it if we want.

Now, I said that your materials used multiple images and multiple channels.  If we look on your main body material alone, we can see that it uses at least 8 different image textures.  Some of these are components of the ultimate diffuse; some of them are not.  We may want to bake additional channels beyond our diffuse color.  Likely choices would be normal, roughness, subsurface scattering characteristics, and glossy (color only.)  Of these, SSS characteristics cannot be baked except by plugging them into emission and baking as emission; how to do so would be its own question.  The others I mentioned can be baked from the menu choices on the bake subsection.  There may be other things we should be baking, and we can't really know without putting the time in to understanding your materials, which again I'm not going to do.  If we choose to bake more than one image for textures, we should not reassign materials until we've completed all bakes.

Frankly, this is the wrong situation to use to learn how to bake textures and use materials.  This is an advanced job that requires a good understanding of all of that to begin with.  I would expect healthy payment for this job (and encourage a different solution to my client.)  You can spend some time getting familiar with baking and materials, after which, you should be able to handle it here, although perhaps with some future questions on BSE, about specific parts of the task.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan! This is very detailed and helpful to understand many aspects of blender functionality for my situation and it’s a wonderful base for studying and maybe developing a better flowing workflow.